# VS2013 MVC 5 Add controller missing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

before posting, I read all the posts related to this query, as well as the ones in asp.net forums. There is a filed bug related to this problem which was filed as solved, but still unsolved in the current version (VS2013.4).

The problem is that my Visual Studio 2013 is missing the "Add Controller" option, so I have no way of scaffolding new controllers in my MVC 5 projects. Some clarifications:

- It is a new MVC5 project, not MVC4->MVC5 migration.
- Updated all nuget packages, all VS related stuff as well.
- Repaired VS2013
- Uninstalled, rebooted and reinstalled VS2013
- Upgraded it
- Installed the .NET Web Tools from the DVD and from internet.
- Changed the project GUIDs as some suggest (btw, those solutions seem to work only for MVC4 or less, not for VS2013 MVC5)

I have a virtual machine at work with win8.1 64bits and VS2013.4 that does have "add controller" option (same config as my home laptop, but in a virtual machine). Also tried to copy the same .csproj settings with no luck.

So, basically, unless someone came across another solution I still may have not tried yet, is to format and reinstall everything.

Comment: Also have this problem (Mvc Add Controller missing) and it's not related to @Brcinho 's response.  Running win7 x64 pc and also running VS2015 and VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is applicable to your case and if it will directly help you, but I had some problems with *Microsoft development tools* and *hidden buttons* when using them on my ***touch screen enabled laptop***

The solution was to **turn off windows/controls scaling** in **Control panel** (set it back to 100%)